# use javascript .on and .editableselect with one html id

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a **select input** which **I want** to make both **editable** and use an **ajax request** that uses the on change JS function. However, only one of the function works since I have used the id of select input twice. I have tried to such for a case related to mine [but the one I got](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3) is so far from addressing my problem. Its a Javascript, HTML/bootstrap issue though I am using laravel.
Here is the code:
**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Product Name</label>
    <select name="stock_name" id="stock_name" class="form-control">
        <option value="" hidden>Select Product Name</option>
        @foreach ($stocks as $stock)
            <option value="{{ $stock->stock_name }}">{{ $stock->stock_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS part in same file**

```
<script>
    $('#stock_name').editableSelect({
        effects: 'slide',
        duration: 600
    });

</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#stock_name").on('change', function () {
            var stock_name = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/sales-price/getunitsellingprice/'+stock_name,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#unit_selling_price").val(response);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the editable-select event listening is different than default. In order to listen to a change event, you should do like in the example below.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#stock_name").on('select.editable-select', function (event, element) {
            var stock_name = element.val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/sales-price/getunitsellingprice/'+stock_name,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#unit_selling_price").val(response);
                },
            });
        });
    });
```